# How can I populate this php form with data from my DB and then be able to update/edit it?

Tags: php

What I am trying to do is create a button on a database that when clicked allows you to edit the row. This also requires the user to be able to see the row so that they know what they are editing. As of now, my table has an edit button on each row that when clicked takes you to the proper page. For example, if you click edit on a row with ID=23, you will be taken to http://website.com/filepath/editForm.php?id=23

The problem is, the fields are all blank and even if you fill them out yourself, they do not update the table. I will post the editform.php and if requested the view.php as well.

```
    <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Untitled Document</title>
</head>

<body>
</form>


<?php
// Only process the form if $_POST isn't empty
if ( ! empty( $_POST ) ) {

  // Connect to MySQL
  $mysqli = new mysqli( 'localhost', 'user', 'mypass', 'dbname' );

  // Check our connection
  if ( $mysqli->connect_error ) {
    die( 'Connect Error: ' . $mysqli->connect_errno . ': ' . $mysqli->connect_error );
  }                 
                    $ID=$_POST['ID'] ;
                    $RYP=$_POST['RYP'] ;
                    $SHE=$_POST['SHE'] ;
                    $SCO=$_POST['SCO'] ;
                    $CName=$_POST['CName'] ;
                    $Contact= $_POST['Contact'] ;                   
                    $Address=$_POST['Address'] ;
                    $City=$_POST['City'] ;
                    $State=$_POST['State'] ;
                    $Zip=$_POST['Zip'] ;
                    $Phone1=$_POST['Phone1'] ;
                    $Phone2=$_POST['Phone2'] ;
                    $EMail=$_POST['EMail'] ;
                    $Web=$_POST['Web'] ;


        $sql = ("SELECT * FROM DEALERS WHERE 'ID' = $ID");

        $sql = ("UPDATE dealers WHERE `ID`='$ID'(RYP, SHE, SCO, CName,Contact,Address,City, State, Zip, Phone1, Phone2, EMail, Web) 
         VALUES ('$RYP','$SHE','$SCO','$CName','$Contact','$Address','$City', '$State','$Zip','$Phone1','$Phone2','$EMail','$Web')"); 


            }
?>

        <form method="post">
<table>
<tr>
        <td>RYP</td>
        <td><input type="checkbox" name="author" value="<?php $row['RYP'] ?>" class="form-control"/></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>SHE</td>
        <td><input type="checkbox" name="author" value="<?php $row['SHE'] ?>" class="form-control"/></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>SCO</td>
        <td><input type="checkbox" name="author" value="<?php $row['SCO'] ?>" class="form-control"/></td>
    </tr>
<tr>
        <td>Contact</td>
        <td><input type="text" name="author" value="<?php $row['Contact'] ?>" class="form-control"/></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Address</td>
        <td><input type="text" name="name" value="<?php $row['Address'] ?>" class="form-control"/></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>City</td>
        <td><input type="text" name="copy" value="<?php $row['City'] ?>" class="form-control"/></td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
        <td>State</td>
        <td><input type="text" name="copy" value="<?php $row['State'] ?>" class="form-control"/></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Zip</td>
        <td><input type="text" name="copy" value="<?php $row['Zip'] ?>" class="form-control"/></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Phone1</td>
        <td><input type="text" name="copy" value="<?php $row['Phone1'] ?>" class="form-control"/></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Phone2</td>
        <td><input type="text" name="copy" value="<?php $row['Phone2'] ?>" class="form-control"/></td>
    </tr><tr>
        <td>EMail</td>
        <td><input type="text" name="copy" value="<?php $row['EMail'] ?>" class="form-control"/></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Web</td>
        <td><input type="text" name="copy" value="<?php $row['Web'] ?>" class="form-control"/></td>
    </tr>
<tr>
        <td>CName</td>
        <td><input type="text" name="title"  value="<?php $row['CName'] ?>"class="form-control"/></td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td><input type="submit" name="submit" value="submit" class="btn btn-success btn-lg"/></td>
    </tr>
</table>
</form></body>
```

Comment: `value="<?php $row['RYP'] ?>"` (from your inputs) you never `echo` any of these values, you basically do noting with them - so the input will always read as `value=""` (empty) when the script loads. And you never actually run any of these queries! So no data is fetched -- Furthermore, take a look at [`error_reporting(E_ALL);`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php)
[`ini_set('display_errors', 1);`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.ini-set.php), will likely yield a lot of warnings from undefined variables.

Comment: And you have a lot of inputs with the same `name` attribute.

Answer (score -1):

I like to do this sort of think with a hidden id field.

```
<input type="hidden" name="id" value="<?php $row['id'] ?>">
```

if you are looking to do this via url then you will need

```
$id = $_GET['id'];
```

Example of hidden id

```
 <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Untitled Document</title>
</head>

<body>
</form>


<?php
// Only process the form if $_POST isn't empty
if ( ! empty( $_POST ) ) {

  // Connect to MySQL
  $mysqli = new mysqli( 'localhost', 'user', 'mypass', 'dbname' );

  // Check our connection
  if ( $mysqli->connect_error ) {
    die( 'Connect Error: ' . $mysqli->connect_errno . ': ' . $mysqli->connect_error );
  }                 
                    $ID=$_POST['ID'] ;
                    $RYP=$_POST['RYP'] ;
                    $SHE=$_POST['SHE'] ;
                    $SCO=$_POST['SCO'] ;
                    $CName=$_POST['CName'] ;
                    $Contact= $_POST['Contact'] ;                   
                    $Address=$_POST['Address'] ;
                    $City=$_POST['City'] ;
                    $State=$_POST['State'] ;
                    $Zip=$_POST['Zip'] ;
                    $Phone1=$_POST['Phone1'] ;
                    $Phone2=$_POST['Phone2'] ;
                    $EMail=$_POST['EMail'] ;
                    $Web=$_POST['Web'] ;


        $sql = ("SELECT * FROM DEALERS WHERE 'ID' = $ID");

        $sql = ("UPDATE dealers WHERE `ID`='$ID'(RYP, SHE, SCO, CName,Contact,Address,City, State, Zip, Phone1, Phone2, EMail, Web) 
         VALUES ('$RYP','$SHE','$SCO','$CName','$Contact','$Address','$City', '$State','$Zip','$Phone1','$Phone2','$EMail','$Web')"); 


            }
?>

        <form method="post">
<table>
<tr>
        <td>RYP</td>
        <td><input type="checkbox" name="author" value="<?php $row['RYP'] ?>" class="form-control"/></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>SHE</td>
        <td><input type="checkbox" name="author" value="<?php $row['SHE'] ?>" class="form-control"/></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>SCO</td>
        <td><input type="checkbox" name="author" value="<?php $row['SCO'] ?>" class="form-control"/></td>
    </tr>
<tr>
        <td>Contact</td>
        <td><input type="text" name="author" value="<?php $row['Contact'] ?>" class="form-control"/></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Address</td>
        <td><input type="text" name="name" value="<?php $row['Address'] ?>" class="form-control"/></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>City</td>
        <td><input type="text" name="copy" value="<?php $row['City'] ?>" class="form-control"/></td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
        <td>State</td>
        <td><input type="text" name="copy" value="<?php $row['State'] ?>" class="form-control"/></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Zip</td>
        <td><input type="text" name="copy" value="<?php $row['Zip'] ?>" class="form-control"/></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Phone1</td>
        <td><input type="text" name="copy" value="<?php $row['Phone1'] ?>" class="form-control"/></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Phone2</td>
        <td><input type="text" name="copy" value="<?php $row['Phone2'] ?>" class="form-control"/></td>
    </tr><tr>
        <td>EMail</td>
        <td><input type="text" name="copy" value="<?php $row['EMail'] ?>" class="form-control"/></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Web</td>
        <td><input type="text" name="copy" value="<?php $row['Web'] ?>" class="form-control"/></td>
    </tr>
<tr>
        <td>CName</td>
        <td><input type="text" name="title"  value="<?php $row['CName'] ?>"class="form-control"/></td>
    </tr>

    <input type="hidden" name="id" value="<?php $row['id'] ?>">

    <tr>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td><input type="submit" name="submit" value="submit" class="btn btn-success btn-lg"/></td>
    </tr>
</table>
</form></body>
```

and finally a url example

```
 <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Untitled Document</title>
</head>

<body>
</form>


<?php
// Only process the form if $_POST isn't empty
if ( ! empty( $_POST ) ) {

  // Connect to MySQL
  $mysqli = new mysqli( 'localhost', 'user', 'mypass', 'dbname' );

  // Check our connection
  if ( $mysqli->connect_error ) {
    die( 'Connect Error: ' . $mysqli->connect_errno . ': ' . $mysqli->connect_error );
  }                 
                    $ID=$_POST['ID'] ;
                    $RYP=$_POST['RYP'] ;
                    $SHE=$_POST['SHE'] ;
                    $SCO=$_POST['SCO'] ;
                    $CName=$_POST['CName'] ;
                    $Contact= $_POST['Contact'] ;                   
                    $Address=$_POST['Address'] ;
                    $City=$_POST['City'] ;
                    $State=$_POST['State'] ;
                    $Zip=$_POST['Zip'] ;
                    $Phone1=$_POST['Phone1'] ;
                    $Phone2=$_POST['Phone2'] ;
                    $EMail=$_POST['EMail'] ;
                    $Web=$_POST['Web'] ;

                    $url_id = $_GET['id'];


        $sql = ("SELECT * FROM DEALERS WHERE 'ID' = $url_id");

        $sql = ("UPDATE dealers WHERE `ID`='$ID'(RYP, SHE, SCO, CName,Contact,Address,City, State, Zip, Phone1, Phone2, EMail, Web) 
         VALUES ('$RYP','$SHE','$SCO','$CName','$Contact','$Address','$City', '$State','$Zip','$Phone1','$Phone2','$EMail','$Web')"); 


            }
?>

        <form method="post">
<table>
<tr>
        <td>RYP</td>
        <td><input type="checkbox" name="author" value="<?php $row['RYP'] ?>" class="form-control"/></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>SHE</td>
        <td><input type="checkbox" name="author" value="<?php $row['SHE'] ?>" class="form-control"/></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>SCO</td>
        <td><input type="checkbox" name="author" value="<?php $row['SCO'] ?>" class="form-control"/></td>
    </tr>
<tr>
        <td>Contact</td>
        <td><input type="text" name="author" value="<?php $row['Contact'] ?>" class="form-control"/></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Address</td>
        <td><input type="text" name="name" value="<?php $row['Address'] ?>" class="form-control"/></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>City</td>
        <td><input type="text" name="copy" value="<?php $row['City'] ?>" class="form-control"/></td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
        <td>State</td>
        <td><input type="text" name="copy" value="<?php $row['State'] ?>" class="form-control"/></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Zip</td>
        <td><input type="text" name="copy" value="<?php $row['Zip'] ?>" class="form-control"/></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Phone1</td>
        <td><input type="text" name="copy" value="<?php $row['Phone1'] ?>" class="form-control"/></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Phone2</td>
        <td><input type="text" name="copy" value="<?php $row['Phone2'] ?>" class="form-control"/></td>
    </tr><tr>
        <td>EMail</td>
        <td><input type="text" name="copy" value="<?php $row['EMail'] ?>" class="form-control"/></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Web</td>
        <td><input type="text" name="copy" value="<?php $row['Web'] ?>" class="form-control"/></td>
    </tr>
<tr>
        <td>CName</td>
        <td><input type="text" name="title"  value="<?php $row['CName'] ?>"class="form-control"/></td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td><input type="submit" name="submit" value="submit" class="btn btn-success btn-lg"/></td>
    </tr>
</table>
</form></body>
```

I would also take a look at MYSQLI Or PDO it appears you are using older outdated and perhaps unsafe methords